# CS:GO How to calculate float values

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive

I am aware that there are several external sites to calculate the float of an item. But how do those sites calculate the float using the inspect link? What API returns this information or if there is an algorithm to calculate the float value.

Comment: For those of us who don't play CS:GO like me, what is "the float of an item"?

Comment: @pppery the float value determines the skin quality of that item between 0 (factory new) and 1 (worn off). The value is predetermined by the game and doesn't change ever, even after trading it or using the weapon.

Comment: And there is already an answer to this on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33543472/how-to-get-the-float-value-of-csgo-market-items)